# Is it possible to get sum without change sql_mode?

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, sql-mode

I have a problem to get `SUM` value from multiple table using join statement. The error is:

> this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Is it possible to get sum without change `sql_mode`? If possible, how to make a SQL statement to?

**Table `fuel`:**

```
vehicle_id | liter
-----------+-----------
         2 | 43.5
         4 | 78.3
         8 | 20.5
```

**Table `usage`:**

```
date_usage | vehicle_id
-----------+-----------
2019-10-01 |  8
2019-10-15 |  2
2019-10-20 |  8
2019-10-20 |  4
2019-11-02 |  8
```

The SQL statement is below:

```
SELECT fuel.vehicle_id, SUM(fuel.liter), usage.date_usage
FROM fuel
LEFT JOIN usage ON fuel.vehicle_id = usage.vehicle_id
WHERE fuel.vehicle_id='8'
AND usage.date_usage >='2019-10-01' AND usage.date_usage <='2019-10-31'
GROUP BY fuel.vehicle_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two possibilities to solve this:

- Remove column `usage.date_usage` from `SELECT`.
- Use a [aggregate function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html) on column `usage.date_usage` too:

  - `MAX` to get the highest value of the column.
  - `MIN` to get the lowest value of the column.
  - [`ANY_VALUE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value) to get any value of the column.

So your query can look like the following (using `MAX` on column `usage.date_usage`):

```
SELECT fuel.vehicle_id, SUM(fuel.liter), MAX(`usage`.date_usage)
FROM fuel LEFT JOIN `usage` ON fuel.vehicle_id = `usage`.vehicle_id
WHERE fuel.vehicle_id = 8
  AND `usage`.date_usage BETWEEN '2019-10-01' AND '2019-10-31'
GROUP BY fuel.vehicle_id
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=611f8eed0854a4fee35a48212226b36e)

**Note:** be careful using words like `usage` as identifiers (e.g. table and column names) in MySQL. There are [keywords and reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) you should avoid or quote with backticks.